# Click event on a (Context)MenuItem of a ListBox (XamlParseException)

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a ListBox and within it multiple ListBoxItem objects. When the user right-clicks on a ListBoxItem a ContextMenu should appear with some MenuItem objects. The problem that I have is that when I put a Click event on the MenuItem objects I get a XamlParseException stating the following:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Set connectionId threw an exception.' Line number '31' and line >position '34'.

I have to admit that I don't fully understand styles and resources and the other aspects of WPF. When I was designing this I just copied my code from the Internet. The code is as follows:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" MouseDoubleClick="MainListBox_MouseDoubleClick" Name="mainListBox" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Click="OpenMenuItem_Click" Header="Open"/>
                        <Separator/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Cut"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
                        <Separator/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Rename"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

It works when I remove the Click event but of course the ContextMenu becomes useless.

Comment: please, include relevant codes especially which the error message refer as in `'Set connectionId threw an exception.' Line number '31' and line >position '34'`. What is in line 31??

Comment: The error occured in PresentationFramework.dll, right? Your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: Consider using `MenuItem.Command` rather than Click events. You can create a custom `RoutedCommand` or `RoutedUICommand`, or in this case you can use a pre-existing set of commands. `ApplicationCommands.Open`, `ApplicationCommands.Cut`, `ApplicationCommands.Copy`, and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign ContextMenu for ListBoxItem as given below.

```
   <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  MouseDoubleClick="MainListBox_MouseDoubleClick" Name="mainListBox" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="CMenu">
                <MenuItem Click="OpenMenuItem_Click" Header="Open"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Cut"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Rename"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.Resources>            
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CMenu}"/>      
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Test1"/>
    </ListBox>
```